# GraphQL - Behaviours

Tags: graphql

I have an headless site that is using GraphQL and we have one query that need to do some calculation before returning the results.

I was planing to create a behaviours in Craft with a property that return the result.

If I'm querying the entry :

```
Entry::find()->section('xyz')->id('1')->one()->totalResult
```

The behaviours return what it is supposed.

If i'm building a GraphQL query I've got an error saying that the field cannot be query.

```
query MyQuery {
  product {
    id, title, totalResult
  }
}
```

Is there a way for GraphQL to have access to this property or is there a simple workaround to create a custom query without having to create a separate api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your field into GraphQL by `TypeManager::EVENT_DEFINE_GQL_TYPE_FIELDS event` here is an example:

```
Event::on(
            TypeManager::class,
            TypeManager::EVENT_DEFINE_GQL_TYPE_FIELDS,
            static function(DefineGqlTypeFieldsEvent $event) {
                if ($event->typeName === 'your_entry_type') {
                $event->fields['totalResults'] = [
                    'name' => 'totalResults',
                    'type' => Type::string(,
                    'resolve' => function($source) {
                        /** @var Entry $event */
                        $entry = $source;
                        return $entry->totalResults;
                    }
                ];
            }
             
            }
        );
```

Please note `your_entry_type` is the typeName, if I am not wrong the format is section_entryType_type